# Looking for "test execution manager" software to manage automated tests

Tags: testing, hudson, automated-tests, functional-testing

We develop several products and already have extensive unit-tests and fully automated functional tests for them. Problem is that those tests don't run frequently, just manually by developer or just before shipping a new version.

I'm looking for a "test execution manager" software which will allow:

- **defining test suites** as a collection of my existing tests ;
- **executing the test suites** on multiple machines in a our test lab ;
- **collecting results** and **presenting** them nicely ;
- preserve test **execution history** and results

Most "testing solutions" I've found concentrate on "writing automated tests" (which we already have working) or closely integrate with other aspects of software development, like defining requirements and filing bugs (which we have and don't want to change).

- **Can anyone recommend a simple and flexible software to do the above without forcing specific development processes?**
- I though on using (or abusing) **Hudson CI** for this. Hudson can already run tests, collect results and present them, both periodically or due to code commit; but it was not designed for test suite definition. Any input from experienced Hudson users on this idea is appreciated..

Comment: It would help if you explained a bit more about your tests. how are they implemented (what languages, frameworks?)

Comment: I have unit-tests implemented in c++ (with CxxTest) and authomated application testing implemented in python, without any specific FW. Tests are typically run in virtual machines on ESX or manually on physical machine. Also I have Hudson for nightly build and CI and all code is managed in SVN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, our developers are not allowed to check in code without running the unit tests. We also run a CI server (Hudson), which builds after a commit and runs the unit tests. We are working on getting the functional tests implemented for the nightly builds.

You said your developers test the software? This is a bad thing. At least let a developer that is *not* familiar with the code to test your app otherwise you are likely to overlook some bugs, because their existence was ruled out by the developer writing the code. Additionally, who writes the functional tests? Developers again? You should get your BA's to write them. Always remember, four eyes see more than two.

So after all that said, I assume, that the unit tests, will always be run before code is checked into your SCM. The following is targeted primarily at the functional tests.

Simple solution:

- You can always create scripts to bundle your tests (batch or shell script that runs the individual test).
- Executing of test suites is actually one of the purposes of Hudson
- Collecting and presenting results, that is what Hudson is for
- See above, can be done with Hudson, without abusing it.

A good solution:

Did you look at tools like [IBM Rational Quality Manager](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/rqm/)? Depending on the test tools you use, you might want to use a test management tool different one. Oracle also offers a tool for it. Don't be mistaken usually these tools can be fairly expensive and offer way more than you want to use. With a little bit help from google you should find something that suits your needs. My keywords were "centralized test management".

In case you use FitNesse for your functional test. You can define suites in FitNesse and I think a suite can be part of a larger suite. FitNesse definitely keeps historic test data. The test can be run from command line which enables you to run the tests from ant or maven.

If you use a unit test framework for your functional testing you can also run them as part of an nightly build and schedule it using your CI server (Hudson or Cruise Control or ...)

Comment: We too run UT on each commit and now want to climb to the next level and have some basic functional tests run every night and a full functional test suite run each week.

Indid, our developers also develop the automated testing; your note on having a seperate developer write the test is correct, we should be more explicit about this.

The choice I face now is between a fast-and-chip solution which will use hudson for test management or look into more complex and complete solutions. So I try to get the word from guys which have it working. I understand you'd go for Hudson.
Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not recommending Hudson per se. That's why I mentioned RQM, which can manage RFT, RPT, and other tools. In your case it sounded like you've already written your tests and only need to group them (batch/shell script) as well as a way to distribute and start them on different servers (e.g. Hudson). You also want to gather the results and present them in a nice way (e.g. Hudson). If you have the budget, you might be better off, with an off the shelf solution (hopefully faster implemented). Your self written tests (assumption: not a standard output format), will need integration in both cases.

Comment: Upvote for **developers are not allowed to check in code without running the unit tests**